# unable to get complete data posted using $_post in php

Tags: php, html

I have set my bulk data in table form like as shown in below image

[image: bulk data in table form]

There is 350+ row in the table and I am getting this data using the `$_Post` method but I am unable to get complete data I get only 125 row.

Comment: Would be nice to have some code. Please can you show us what you've tried.

Comment: $_POST have a limit of characters. It's really bigger than $_GET, but they have it. If you have lot of information to send, you need to send it on a file or on multiple requests.

Comment: Check in your php config what the max size of your $_POST is.

Comment: Do you reach some of the following limits of the php configuration? `max_input_vars` or `post_max_size`